# How can I add elements to a 2d array using only one for loop?

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

```
int j = 0;
```

I want to use only one for:

```
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
{
    int randomC = (int) (Math.random()*str.length());
    char character;

    if(i<25)
    {
```

Because I want to use the `charAt()` function

```
character = str.charAt(i);
regular.set_character(character);
regular.set_point();

System.out.print(regular.get_character());

if(j==5)
    j==0;
```

I want to add elements to this `array`:
Please tell me a way to add elements by using one for to add elements to every cell of my 5x5 array.

```
    array[i][j] = regular.get_character();
    }
}
```

Comment: Need more info.  I assume this is a C question, but what type is array?

Comment: You can use the modulo operator % together with the / to fill an array in one loop.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Looks like Java, I would guess, going by the `System.out.print()` call.

Comment: Yes it is Java I need only one loop to add elements in my 5x5 2d array. What control statements should I use?